# Moment-timezone can't load data in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, timezone, aws-lambda, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm using `moment-timezone@0.5.23`.

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
...
const now = moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(now.format('dddd');
```

This works well when I run it on my laptop. However, when I deploy the code to my **AWS Lambda** function running on **Node 8.10**, I see this in the log

```
Moment Timezone has no data for "America/Los_Angeles". See 
http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.
```

As the result, I end up with the time of either `America/New_York` or UTC instead of `America/Los_Angeles`.

I've tried to copied the packed data over and loaded it manually (`moment.tz.load(require('./latest'));`) but still got the same error.

Any way to make `moment-timezone` work properly on AWS Lambda?

Thanks,

Comment: I figured out the problem. In my actually code, I passed in the timezone code from another function which includes extra quotes in it. There's no problem with moment-timezone here. I'm going to close this question to avoid confusion.